# Swift 3/iOS UIView not updating after retrieving remote JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiview, reload

I have a `UITableView` with a list of users. When you tap on a row, the uid of the user is passed to the `UIViewController` detail view. A `URLRequest` is made to retrieve `JSON` data of the user (username, avatar, etc). However, the detail view inconsistently updates the information. Sometimes it'll show the users' name, avatar, etc but other times it'll show nothing or it'll only show the username or only show the avatar, etc.

In the `fetchUser()` method, I have a `print("Username: \(self.user.username)")` that shows the correct data is being retrieved 100% of the time but it won't display it 100% of the time in the view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var networthLabel: UILabel!

    var user: User!
    var uid: Int?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        fetchUser()
    }

    func reloadView() {
        self.usernameLabel.text = user.username
        self.networthLabel.text = "$" + NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: Int((user.networth)!)! as NSNumber, number: NumberFormatter.Style.decimal)
        self.avatarImageView.downloadImage(from: user.avatar!)
        circularImage(photoImageView: self.avatarImageView)
    }

    func fetchUser() {
        // Post user data to server
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/test/profile")
        let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL);
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "uid=\(uid!)"

        urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            if (error != nil) {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            } // end if

            self.user = User()

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : AnyObject]

                if let parseJSON = json?["data"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

                    for userFromJson in parseJSON {

                        let userData = User()

                        if let uid = userFromJson["uid"] as? String,
                            let username = userFromJson["username"] as? String,
                            let networth = userFromJson["networth"] as? String,
                            let avatar = userFromJson["avatar"] as? String {

                            userData.uid = Int(uid)
                            userData.username = username
                            userData.networth = networth
                            userData.avatar = avatar

                            self.usernameLabel.text = username
                            self.networthLabel.text = networth
                            self.avatarImageView.downloadImage(from: avatar)
                            circularImage(photoImageView: self.avatarImageView)

                        } // end if

                        self.user = userData

                    } // end for

                } // end if

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Username: \(self.user.username)")
                    self.reloadView()
                }

            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, call fetch user in `viewWillAppear` like this:

`override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        fetchUser()
    }`

Then, change the code here like I did, don't use the `reloadView` function you had, instead, update the UI elements on the main thread at the end of the `fetchUser` function. I also changed it so you weren't updating the UI twice because you have 4 lines at the bottom of the `if let uid = ...` statement in `fetchUser` which updated UI elements that wasn't in the main thread which is why in my version I removed those 4 lines of code. Let me know if this worked for you.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        } // end if

        self.user = User()

        do {

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : AnyObject]

            if let parseJSON = json?["data"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

                for userFromJson in parseJSON {

                    let userData = User()

                    if let uid = userFromJson["uid"] as? String,
                        let username = userFromJson["username"] as? String,
                        let networth = userFromJson["networth"] as? String,
                        let avatar = userFromJson["avatar"] as? String {

                        userData.uid = Int(uid)
                        userData.username = username
                        userData.networth = networth
                        userData.avatar = avatar

                    } // end if

                    self.user = userData

                } // end for

            } // end if

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.usernameLabel.text = user.username
                self.networthLabel.text = "$" + NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: Int((user.networth)!)! as NSNumber, number: NumberFormatter.Style.decimal)
                self.avatarImageView.downloadImage(from: user.avatar!)
                circularImage(photoImageView: self.avatarImageView)
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you, Timmy! This fixed it! I wastee so many hours trying to figure it out. I think I was getting confused with the multi threading. Much appreciated for the help and modified code example!

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. *strictly speaking*, all accesses to `UIView` object should be on the main thread. You're dispatching to the main thread to call `reloadView`, but should probably also do it when you're settings the "username" and "net worth" values on the labels
2. are you *sure* that the labels are blank? Could it be an autolayout problem instead? (Try setting the background colour of the labels to yellow, to check that they're the correct size. Sometimes autolayout can squash views down to nothing if there are conflicting constraints)

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the suggestions. You were right with your first suggestion. I was getting mixed up with the multi threading and how it worked. Much appreciated!